# How to test localized widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I added l10n to my flutter app as suggested in the [flutter docs](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/), it is suggested to get the localizations with a static method like this:

```
static DemoLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
  return Localizations.of<DemoLocalizations>(context, DemoLocalizations);
}
```

This works fine when running the app, but when I try to test my widgets, the returned value is always null.

Is there any easy way to provide the localizations within the tests?

For now I'm passing through the localizations via DI, but it is quite an overhead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can wrap the widget you want to tests into a `Localizations`

```
Localizations(
  delegates: [
    yourDelegate
  ],
  locale: Locale('en'),
  child: YourWidget(),
);
```

Comment: This works for me. It was important to wait for the delegate's Future to complete. I used `await tester.pumpAndSettle();` to achieve this.

Comment: If you are using "gen_l10n app_localizations" have a look here for an easy to use utility function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73248298/4934628

Answer (score 5):

The above answer didn't help because I was calling strings from `json` file. The [medium blog](https://medium.com/@dooboolab/testing-localized-widget-in-flutter-3bfa5492bc84) actually handled my problem in solving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an universal utility function to make the usage of localization easier inside widget testing:

```
// Don't forget the import
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

...

Future<AppLocalizations> getLocalizations(WidgetTester t) async {
  late AppLocalizations result;
  await t.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      home: Material(
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            result = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return result;
}
```

In order to grab a localized text in one line you just have to call

```
 await getLocalizations(t).then((l) => l.YOUR_KEY_HERE)
```

then. Maybe it's also useful for someone :)

Comment: It's not working for me :( The following LateError was thrown running a test:
LateInitializationError: Local `result` has not been initialized

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read this issues. In case file json over 10kb, it cannot load assets. We should keep following and wait Flutter team fix it or real solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22193

Comment: A other way I used linux command to split whole file into some smaller fille and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want test existing widgets with in a specific language, you can get the localization by:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
...
(await GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate.load(Locale('en'))).okButtonLabel
```

or

```dart
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
...
(await GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate.load(Locale('en'))).myCustomLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

It's modifiable of [How to test localized widgets in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463714/how-to-test-localized-widgets-in-flutter/73248298#73248298)

U need to add after return `await t.pumpAndSettle();`

Full code:

```dart
  Future<AppLocalizations> getLocalizationsUnderTests(
    WidgetTester t,
  ) async {
    late AppLocalizations result;
    await t.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate>[
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
        locale: const Locale('en'),
        home: Material(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              result = AppLocalizations.of(context);
              debugPrint('[DEBUG]: locale: $result');

              // The builder function must return a widget.
              return const Placeholder();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    await t.pumpAndSettle();
    return result;
  }
```